# Why does the current decrease if the length of the wire in a circuit increases?

Tags: circuits

[image]

I have a circuit with a battery, a bulb and an ammeter with the length of the wire "l".

- If the circuit is closed, the ammeter shows x amps as the reading.
- When the length of the wire is doubled, the ammeter drops to x/2 amps.

Why is there a reason for a inverse proportional relationship between length of the wire and current?

Comment: What you describe just won't happen in a normal circuit. it could only happen if the series resistance of the light bulb and battery and power switch each are much lower than wiring resistance. Which is untrue for the vast majority of light bulbs, and some batteries.

Comment: `Why is there a reason for a proportional relationship between length of the wire and current` - well you've just asserted the opposite so somewhere, inside your head, there is a mix-up that needs to be resolved.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry for the wrong wording , its inversely proportional , Pardoning that , could u post an answer [ Edited by a moderator. Vulgar word removed. See the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) ]

Comment: Ohm's law is the answer.

Comment: http://ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/socratic/model/mod_vir.pdf

Comment: @AarushiAgarwal, please keep your conversation polite. It's site policy.

Answer (score 3):

The wire is a resistor, and the resistance is proportional to its length.

Let’s say its resistance is $$R = r\times l $$ where r is the resistance per length (in ohms per meter) and l is the length in meters.

Then if we ignore the resistance of the rest of the circuit, then:
$$ U = R\times I$$
$$ U = r\times l\times I$$

$$I = \frac{U}{r\times l}
$$
With U fixed (doesn’t happen in real life), r fixed (it depends on the gauge of the wire), then I is indeed inversely proportional to the length of the wire: if you double the length, current is halved.

In real life it will not be as simple because the bulb and battery and the switch all have their own resistance, so it would need quite a long length of thin wire to approximate that, but current would still be lower when you increase the length of the wire.

Answer (score 2):

This is another of those absurdly stupid questions coming from a bad textbook or written by a "professor" who has never built a circuit.

Real-life lamps don't have zero resistance. If you actually build this circuit of reasonable components, e.g. using 18AWG wire, a 100W light bulb, and 240V AC supply, the wire will have to be rather long for the current to roughly decrease by half by increasing the wire length twice.

Such a light bulb has about \$580\ \Omega\$ resistance operating at full power. For the current to drop by half with 10% error when doubling the length of wire, the wire resistance would need to be about 10x the bulb resistance.

The bulb's resistance depends highly nonlinearly on the RMS current. A cold bulb is "almost" a short circuit, but a hot one can have resistance in hundreds of Ohms if it's rated for mains voltages.

The bulb will be running much cooler with the added resistor. Let's say it'll have about 1/10th of its full power resistance, or about \$58\ \Omega\$. We would need wire resistance of about \$600\ \Omega\$, or more, to demonstrate the current halving effect with 10% error. And 10x higher resistance to cut the error to about 1%.

18AWG wire - perfectly usable with 100W desk lamps - is about \$6.4\ \Omega\$ per 1000 feet (about 300m). To get \$600\ \Omega\$, we'll need about 100,000 feet, or 30km of wire, to demonstrate the "current halving" with 10% error. For ~1% error you'll need 300km of wire...

So, the question is pretty bad, because the setup runs against expectations. For any reasonable length of wire, the wire must be extremely thin, and the lamp must be cold, so it'll have low resistance. The lamp must be oversized in power rating vs. the actual power it outputs in the circuit. The parasitic resistances in the dark lamp, ammeter and voltage source must be low.

Practically speaking, you'd have to be using a low voltage supply, say 12V, a high power incandescent light bulb, say 100W-500W halogen rated for 12V-24V, and thin wire - say AWG40 with \$1\ \Omega/\text{ft}\$ resistance, to keep wire lengths reasonable to demonstrate the effect with a sufficiently low error.

As the wire length is increased, the error decreases, in the limit to 0% with "infinitely long" wire. In practical circuits with practical components, you can easily demonstrate the current halving with 0.1% error, but the wire will be long (many meters) and very thin - hair-thin or even thinner than that!

Just handling such a thin wire, e.g. winding it on a spool without accidentally breaking it, is much trickier than it looks. I'd say AWG40 is the thinnest wire that can be "easily" handled without breaking it with some care. AWG46, with half the diameter of AWG40 and 1/4 of its yield strength, gets diabolically hard to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Let say wire has a resistance r and the lamp has resistance R.

According to Ohm's law I(current) = V/(r+R).

You have increased the length which will increase the resistance of the wire because resistance is equal to (pL/A) where p is resistivity and L is the length of the wire. The current will be I = V/(R1+r), so the current will decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the current inversely proportional to the length of wire? The reason is that the resistance of the wire is proportional to the length of wire, AND the resistance of the light-bulb is negligible compared to the resistance of the wire (a highly unusual situation).

The resistance, R, of a wire is:

R = rho * l / A

Where 'rho' is the bulk resistivity of the wire (a material property), 'l' is the length of wire, and 'A' is the cross-sectional area of the wire. You have to use consistent units. For example if 'rho' is given in Ohm meters, then 'l' should be in meters, and 'A' should be in meters squared.

I agree with the others that this scenario and situation makes no sense whatsoever as far as actual engineering practice goes. But even this type of question deserves an answer rather than ridicule, I guess.